# Functions satisfying $f(x+y)+x= f(x)f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f$ be a real valued function such that $f(x+y)+x=f(x)f(y)$, for every $x$ and $y$.

I have tried $x=0$, it seems the exponential function works, but for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ I can't succed to get functions satisfying  $f(x+y)+x=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: Hint: what do you get when you plug in $y=0$?

Comment: Taking $x=0$  we quickly see that $f(0)=1$, but then taking $y=0$ we get $f(x)+x=f(x)$ which is not possible.

Comment: @lulu, not so fast, you can have f(y) = 0

Comment: @Norbert  no...the constant function $0$ does not work, so there must be some value $y_0$ for which $f(y_0)\neq 0$.  Use that one.

Answer (score 9):

There are no such functions.  To see that, suppose we had such a function.  We will derive a contradiction.

First note that the constant function $0$ does not work, hence there must be some value $y_0$ for which $f(y_0)\neq 0$.

Taking $x=0, y=y_0$ then yields $$f(y_0)=f(0)\,f(y_0)\implies f(0)=1$$

Now, taking $y=0$, with no restriction on $x$, we get $$f(x)+x=f(x)$$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

$x = 0, y = 1$, $$f(1) + 0 = f(1)f(0)$$

$x = 1, y = 0$, $$f(1) + 1 = f(1)f(0)$$

This implies $0 = 1$ so no such function exits.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y =0$, it gives

$$f (0)=f (0)^2$$
thus $f (0)=0$ or $f (0)=1$.

Assume $f (0)=0$.

with $x=-y $, we get
$$f (0)+x=f (x)f (-x)=-x $$
which is not possible.

so, $f (0)=1$.

with $x=-y $,
$$1+x=f (x)f (-x)=1-x $$
There is no function satsfying that condition.